# Можно ли так оформить косвенную речь?

Tags: пунктуация

Что касается второй части вашего вопроса, то тут ответ «да, конечно готовы», хотя в некоторых проектных институтах и на предприятиях до сих пор встречается инертность мышления и боязнь всего нового, но это все является результатом информационного голода и пережитками прошлого.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаемый вариант:

Что касается второй части вашего вопроса, то тут ответ «да, конечно готовы», хотя в некоторых проектных институтах и на предприятиях до сих пор встречается инертность мышления и боязнь всего нового, которые, скорее,  являются результатом информационного голода и пережитками прошлого.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

1) Здесь упрощенный вариант оформления прямой речи, которая выполняет функцию члена предложения (нет двоеточия, строчная буква).

2) Не очень удачным показалось сочетание ХОТЯ...НО - оно может быть воспринято как двойной союз.

3) Инерция и инертность - эти слова заимствованы из физики. Инерция - явление сохранения скорости при отсутствии сил, а инертность - свойство тела сохранять скорость. Думаю, что в переносном смысле "инертность мышления" - более точное выражение, к тому же оно является медицинским термином.

Comment: По-моему, надо еще тире: "Тут ответ - "Да, конечно готовы". Ср.: "Ответ тут "Да, конечно готовы".

Comment: И "скорее" здесь может не выделяться, если подразумевается сопоставление: скорее информационный голод, чем вина сотрудников.

Answer (score 0):

Да,все кавычки поставлены правильно.

Answer (score 0):

Инерция мышления, не инертность — так выглядит это устойчивое словосочетание.
Не думаю, что здесь нужны кавычки. И косвенной речи здесь нет.

Фраза активно не нравится, очень коряво.